# preg_match search pattern, stop at character combination

Tags: preg-match

I am trying to pull a whole Mysql statement from a database sql file

```
INSERT INTO `helppages` 
   (`HelpPageID`, `ShowHelpItem`, `HelpRank`, `HelpCategory`, `HelpTitle`, `HelpDescription`, `HelpLink`, `HelpText`, `CMSHelpBar`, `CMSHelpBarAdditional`) 
   VALUES (... characters (Too many to post here, but the expression below grabs all)   ... 
   );
```

The current, though I have been through many variations, expression I am using is:

```
    preg_match("#INSERT INTO `$SearchingTableName` ([!%&'-/:<=>@^`\;\s\d\w\"\#\$\(\)\*\+\,\.\?\[\]\{\}\(\)\\\|©]*?)\)\;\r\n#s", $uploadedfile, $matches);
which gets all the information but I can't get it to stop at the end ");\r\n"
also $SearchingTableName = helppages.
```

### Edit

Sorry the current expression uses look forward

```
preg_match("#INSERT INTO `$SearchingTableName` ([!%&'-/:<=>@^`\;\s\d\w\"\#\$\(\)\*\+\,\.\?\[\]\{\}\(\)\\\|©]*)(?!\)\;\r\n)#s", $uploadedfile, $matches);
```

Also I checked with MSword using );^p and there is only one instance at the end of the Insert

Comment: are there nested SELECT statements in the values part? or it is  basic INSERT INTO without ON DUPLICATE KEY or DELAYED, PRIORITY...

Comment: No Nested selects, just text numbers some html and css. Also basic insert, for example INSERT VALUES (''), (''), ('');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match this kind of string you can't do it only playing with character classes. You need to describe the string structure.

For this simple particular case you can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = <<<EOD
~
# definitions
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<elt>  [^"',)]+ | '(?>[^\\']+|\\.)*' | "(?>[^\\"]+|\\.)*" )
    (?<list> \( \g<elt>? (?: \s* , \s* \g<elt> )* \) )
)

# main pattern
INSERT \s+ (?:INTO \s+)? `$SearchingTableName` \s* \g<list>? \s* VALUES \s*
\g<list> \s* (?: , \s* \g<list> \s* )* ;
~xs
EOD;

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $uploadedfile, $m))
    print_r($m[0]);
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lX3oN2/4)

But keep in mind that parsing a programming language is not an easy task and is full of traps (depending of the syntax) even for the capabilities of the PHP regex engine. *(It's however possible.)*

#### regex features used here:

**delimiters and modifiers:**

The pattern delimiter used here is `~` instead of the classical `/`. There is no literal `~` in the pattern thus it's ok.
The pattern uses two modifiers: `s` and `x`:

- by default the `.` can't match the newline character `\n`. The `s` modifier *(s for singleline mode)* changes this behavior. When used the `.` can match all characters including the newline character. *(Note that you can retrieve this default behavior using `\N` that doesn't match the newline character whatever the mode.)*
- `x` switches on the extended mode. In this mode, whitespaces inside the pattern are ignored. This mode allows too inline comments that begin with a sharp character `#`. This mode is very useful to make readable long patterns using spaces, indentation and comments.

**using named captures**

When you have a long pattern and when you need to reuse several times the same subpatterns, you have the possibility to reuse subpatterns that are written inside capture groups.

A quick example:

You want to match several items separated by commas and composed with 4 digits and 4 letters like this: `1234abcd,5678efgh,9012ijkl,3456mnop`.

The pattern to do that is obviously `^\d{4}[a-z]{4}(?:,\d{4}[a-z]{4})+$`

But if I don't want to write `\d{4}[a-z]{4}` two times, I can put it in a capture group and use an alias for the subpattern in the capture group, like this: `^(\d{4}[a-z]{4})(?:,(?1))+$`.

Here the `(?1)` is an alias for the subpattern inside the capture group 1 *(not the content matched by the subpattern as a backreference `\1` does, but the subpattern itself)* that is `\d{4}[a-z]{4}`.

PCRE, the regex engine used by PHP supports this syntax too `\g<1>` instead of `(?1)`.

But if you have a lot of capture groups in the pattern, it is not always handy to remember what's the number of the capture group you need. This is the reason why you have the possibility to name capturing groups. Example: `^(?<diglet>\d{4}[a-z]{4})(?:,\g<diglet>)+$`

The other advantage of named patterns, except to make the whole pattern more readable, is to add a semantical dimension to the pattern, in the same way you can do it by addying an id attribute to an html tag.

**definition section**

Instead of defining the named subpattern directly in the main pattern like in the previous example, you can use a definition section to put all the subpatterns that would be used in the main pattern. Note that all that is inside this section is only here for definition purpose and doesn't match nothing. It's like a zero-width assertion.

The syntax of this section is : `(?(DEFINE)(?<diglet>\d{4}[a-z]{4}))` *(you can put several named subpatterns inside.)*. The precedant pattern becomes:
`(?(DEFINE)(?<diglet>\d{4}[a-z]{4}))^\g<diglet>(?:,\g<diglet>)+$`

#### the pattern itself:

The first part of the pattern enclosed between `(?(DEFINE)` and `)` consists of subpatterns definitions that will be used later in the main pattern.

The `elt` subpattern describes an item (a column name or a value):

```
[^"',)]+            # all that is not a quote a comma or a closing parenthese:
                    # in the present context this will match numbers and column names
|                   # OR
'(?>[^\\']+|\\.)*'  # string between single quotes (designed to deal with escaped quotes)
|                    
"(?>[^\\"]+|\\.)*"  # same for double quotes
```

The `list` subpattern describes the full list of elements separated by commas between parenthesis. Note that this subpattern use a reference to the `elt` subpattern.

The main pattern needs only to reuse the subpattern `list`.

Comment: imagine that you're a 10 Dan black belt and I am below a white belt ... could you explain that, because I know it works but I can't seem to get it working with my script. Could you possibly use variables, no define constants, Thanks a lot already!

Comment: @James: using variables instead of using named subpatterns will not be helpful. But if you point what you don't understand, I can edit my answer to add more details for this or these particular parts.

Comment: I am not good with short hand and I tried writing the define constants in longhand, because it won't register the shorthand version in my scripts. <?php ?> But I am getting confused with the syntax translation. Basically (?(DEFINE) ) (?<elt> ) (?<list> ) and calling the defined ... I can't translate to old syntax define('elt', [^"',)]+ | '(?>[^\\']+|\\.)*' | "(?>[^\\"]+|\\.)*") ... missing quotes and escapes.

Comment: @James: The definition section inside the pattern has nothing to do with the `define` of the php language, It's not a new syntax, it's a regex feature. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Ahh ... because I was getting confused. I should have started with "I am using PHP" and PCRE does not support the (?{code}) and (??{code}) construction, http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php. So how do I translate this?

Comment: Also what is the meaning of ?> in (?<elt> [^"',)]+ | '(?>[^\\']+|\\.)*' | "(?>[^\\"]+|\\.)*" ). As it is something I've not seen in php preg.

Comment: Thanks got it working ... need to escape literal characters $pattern="~(?(DEFINE)(?<elt>[^\"\'\,)]+|\'(?>[^\\\']+|\\\.)*\'|\"(?>[^\\\"]+|\\\.)*\")(?<list>\(\g<elt>?(?:\s*\,\s*\g<elt>)*\)))INSERT\s+INTO\s+`$SearchingTableName`\s*\g<list>?\s*VALUES\s*\g<list>\s*(?:\,\s*\g<list>\s*)*\;~xs";

Comment: @James: Yes this is the reason why I used the heredoc syntax for the string (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), you don't need to escape backslashes several times.

Comment: @James: About `(?>...)`: this is an atomic group, it is like a non-capturing group. The only difference is that the regex engine is no more allowed to backtrack in the part matched inside parenthesis once the closing parenthesis is reached: http://regular-expressions.info/atomic.html

Comment: To be clear, What I have posted is a fully working php code. You don't need to escape `,` or  `;` (there are not special characters).